# How can we achieve Shared View Model communication between a Fragment and Activity, where the Activity is not the Parent

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-lifecycle, android-viewmodel

I am trying to achieve Fragment to Activity communication given that the Activity is not the parent Activity.

So, I have a `MainActivity` that has a fragment called `ContactListFragment`, while the add button on the `BottomNavigationView` of `MainActivity` is clicked, I am opening another `AddContactActivity` to add a contact. My requirement is to when I am clicking the save button on the `AddContactActivity`, I need to initiate a data-sync with server in `ContactListFragment`. I think the best approach would be to use a Shared View Model for this, but in that Case how should I create the view model so that the lifecycle owner doesn't get changed?

I thought about using the `Application Context` as the owner but I feel like its an overkill for a task like this, and it may produce some consequences down the line when other modules are added to the project.

So is there a way to efficiently implement this approach? Thanks.

Comment: How about using an Interface?

Comment: How do you suggest to implement it? since there is a different activity opening up, How do I make sure `MainActivity` is still in the background before calling the interface implementation?

Comment: "My requirement is to when I am clicking the save button on the AddContactActivity, I need to initiate a data-sync with server in ContactListFragment.". Just do `startActivityForResult` from the list fragment. When you come back from the add screen, send some data in the intent and start the sync in onActivityResult in the list fragment

Comment: well yeah, I mean that is the last option imo. I was hoping for a better solution though, so that I can handle this is in a modular way with as less coupling as I can. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write an interface class with object/objects/Data types you need to sync

```
interface OnSaveClickListener {
    fun onSaveClicked(contact: Contact)
}
```

Now in ContactListFragment class

```
class ContactListFragment : Fragment(), OnSaveClickListener {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        (activity as AddContactACtivity).mOnSaveClickListener = this
    }

   
    override fun onSaveClicked(contact: Contact) {
        // Whatever you want to do with the data
    }
        
}
```

In AddContactActivity,

```
class AddContactActivity {
   var mOnSaveClickListener : OnSaveClickListener? = null

   private void whenYouClickSave(contact: Contact){
       mOnSaveClickListener?.onSaveClicked(contact)
   }
```

Comment: While this is a good solution, It doesn't achieve the loose coupling that I was looking for using a shared view-model. But since it just works I will accept this with a thanks.

Comment: Try using ViewModelFactory explained here if you want to have a single object of a view Model https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/issues/29