# Android/java App: pass data from one activity to another RUNNING activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

In my main activity (A) I have a data gathering process which regularly fills some array with results. At some point the user may want to check on these results and by clicking on a button from A, a new activity (B) starts and displays them. I have done this far, i.e. `startActivity(intent);`

But, I want a bit more: if B is running and data (which resides in A) changes I want to update B's screen to show that. I have seen how to override `onNewIntent(Intent i)` in B and I understand that. But I do not know how to send an intent with updated data from within A to B. I repeat: not when B is created but when B is already running.

I can't seem to find how to retain a reference to B when created from within A. And I can't seem to find how to send anything to B.

Is my design flawed?

Comment: You can perhaps use a shared view model or even an interface?

Comment: @SarahKhan thanks for pointing me to shared view model. I will read on this, it looks a more sane way of passing data to activities. By "interface" do you mean a singleton which will be shared between all activities?

Comment: Simply you can use `MutableLiveData<ArrayList<String>>()` instead of ArrayList in activity A and observe changes in activity B. for more details you can visit https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata

Comment: Singleton class is another way but it's not very much recommended. For example of interface, look the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65932555/how-can-we-achieve-shared-view-model-communication-between-a-fragment-and-activi/65939969#65939969

Comment: @satya-p91 got it thanks

Comment: @SarahKhan  ok getting there thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the advice by @sarahkhan and @satya-p91 (thanks!), to use a ViewModel containing a LiveData.

But I soon realised, being an android nube, that a ViewModel is tied to the life-cycle of the activity it is attached to at creation and will die when the secondary (not Main) activity dies, even if that's a back-button.

In order to get data to be persistant within a ViewModel even if that ViewModel dies when its activity dies is to make it `static`. And so I have something like:

```
public class AllViewModel extends ViewModel {
  static MutableLiveData<List<String>> myData = new ArrayList<>();
...
}
```